# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired due to index?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

After creating an index on a rather small table (approx. 700 rows, 10 colums) I started to get

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired

The index was clusterd on the primary key.
There are no triggers.

All of these errors occured when doing an update via a stored procedure.
After I removed the index I had no more time-out issues.

Setting CommandTimeout did not help.
Does anybody has an idea why this was happening?

**stored procedure (nothing special here)**

```
Update objects set date_last_datacollect=@date_last_datacollect,
date_last_error='',message_last_error=''   where objectid = @objectid
```

**Table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[objects](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[objectid] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[adminid] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[token] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[type] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[date_added] [date] NULL,
[date_last_update] [datetime] NULL,
[date_last_datacollect] [datetime] NULL,
[date_last_error] [datetime] NULL,
[message_last_error] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[active] [bit] NULL,
[logourl] [nchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

edit:
After viewing my table structure I realize it might be due to the missing primary key?

Comment: What is the code you executed? Do you have triggers of that table? Dependencies?

Comment: My crystal ball is frozen and out of order... please show us the **table structure**, tell us what **indexes** you have, and show us **the code** used to query the table.....

Comment: That must be one hell of an index with 700 rows causing a timeout. Is your disk system under heavy load at the same time? What is your timeout setting anyway. If it is only an index on the PK i cannot understand this behaviour. What is the query plan if you execute the same stored procedure in management studio?

Comment: Possibly blocking. If you can reproduce the issue look in `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` whilst the wait is happening.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. No heavy disk load at the moment, and time out is default. I will reproduce the error and check sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating statistics on the table?